Which one is measurable - Proper or Coordinate velocities?
When we measure the velocity of a particle, are we measuring its proper velocity or coordinate velocity. Also, when we do particle physics experiments, how do we measure the four momenta of a particle? As in each component? Do we measure its coordinate velocity and then use a program to convert it to proper velocity or is there a way that can give us that directly?

How do you measure velocity? Write out the events involved and then the calculations you perform, I think it will become clear from it.
